# Juntar propiedades de un objeto

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Estoy intentando transformar un objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
const object = {
  nombre: 'Jhon',
  nombre_2: 'Peter',
  nombre_3: 'Manuel',
  email: 'lorem@gmail.com',
  email_2: 'lorem2@gmail.com',
  email_3: 'lorem3@gmail.com',
};
```

Lo que quiero obtener es esto:

```
const objectReduced = {
  nombre: ['Jhon', 'Peter', 'Manuel'],
  email: ['lorem@gmail.com', 'lorem2@gmail.com', 'lorem3@gmail.com'],
};
```

He intentado muchas veces con el método de array reduce pero me resulta imposible llegar al resultado deseado, ayuda por favor.

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que has querido hacer? ¿A qué le has aplicado un array reduce? Tienes un objeto, y funciona como un diccionario, no como un arreglo.

Comment: Me refiero que, no puedes aplicar un array reduce a un diccionario.

Comment: ¿Dónde se **originan** esos datos? Puede que el problema esté ahí: en un mal planteamiento en el origen que ha producido un objeto complicado que ahora quieres arreglar. **Si puedes, resuelve esto en el origen**. Otro aspecto importante que no queda claro en la pregunta es la variabilidad de los datos, o sea, ¿podría haber en algún caso `nombre_3, nombre_4, nombre_9999`  y `email_999999`? ¿Podría haber casos de 3 nombres y 5 emails por ejemplo? ¿Podría haber claves así: `nombre8, email5`?

Comment: @Jacobo Al intentar usar el método reduce lo estaba haciendo usando Object.entries(object) que retorna un array de todas las propiedades en forma de array, o sea, una array de arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira, éste es un problema que se puede aterrizar de distintas formas y depende de la necesidad que se tenga contemplando el contexto.

Supongamos que las llaves de tu objeto cuando hay duplicados tienen la forma de llave_index, si es así, entonces de manera dinámica podemos crear el objeto.

```
// Sacamos las propiedades del objeto de una forma [llave, valor]
const objectEntries = Object.entries(object);

// Dado que es un array de elementos [llave, valor] usamos el reduce
// currValue es el valor actual o al que lo vamos a transformar = {}
// [key, value] es la entrada de cada elemento del array
objectEntries.reduce((currValue, [key, value]) => {
       // remplazamos el _index de la llave con estructura llave_index con un string vacío, quedando como resultado sólo la llave
       const parsedKey = key.replaceAll(/_.+/g, '');

       // Si la llave no existe en el nuevo objeto entonces lo agregamos como un nuevo array y con el valor indicado, si ya existe entonces sólo le damos push con el valor indicado
       !currValue.hasOwnProperty(parsedKey) ?
            currValue[parsedKey] = [value] : currValue[parsedKey].push(value);

      // Retornamos nuestro nuevo objeto pero ya modificado
      return currValue;
    }, {}};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba tratando de hacer algo parecido, pero no lograba dar con el resultado, gracias a ti lo he resuelto, el único detalle es que esta linea:

`const parsedKey = key.replaceAll(/_.+/g, '');`
marca error: key.replaceAll is not a function

lo resolví reemplazando esa linea por esta:

`const parsedKey = key.split('_')[0]`

y listo, todo perfecto, muchas gracias.